# unordered_map of a hash

Tags: c++, hash, c++14

From some source^, I get a hash buffer of length 20 (SHA-1) for a particular data (say a file or block of bytes). If this given hash (consider it as **string**, not hash) is *not* found in map, then I would pull more information, and insert this information with this hash. To make it clear:

- `unordered_map<Hash_of_20_Bytes, Information>`

It is my map. The key would be a 20-byte buffer, and `Information` is some structure containing detailed information. So, if the *source^* gives me some hash, I would lookup that hash into this Information-map and use/generate appropriately.

The point is, in my case, the given 20-byte hash is guaranteed to not have any collision. However, `unordered_map` would still calculate the (FNV) hash for the key (the key itself being a hash!). Can't I instruct the collection class *not* to generate the hash, instead use the key has unique-key itself (to ensure O(1))?

I am not sure if `unordered_map` computes the hash for integers also (i.e. to reduce the need for additional computation).

One approach is to use a vector of `pair<20-byte, Info>` itself, and do a binary search. However, just to avoid penalty of hash computation (by hash-container) it incurs more penalty of keeping the vector sorted).

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) allows you to set the hash-function to be used. Generically using a special "type" for the key and then have a specialization of [`std::hash`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash) for that type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the hash as-is anyway, since `unordered_map` expects a `size_t` as hash, not a 20 bytes buffer.

Now, what you can do is to provide an extremely simple custom hash function: since the input is already a good hash you can just take the first `sizeof(size_t)` bytes and brutally `memcpy` them into a `size_t`, discarding all the others. I don't know think you'll get incredible performance speedups, but it doesn't cost much to try this out.

> Can't I instruct the collection class *not* to generate the hash, instead, use the key has unique-key itself (to ensure O(1))?

The underlying assumption here is flawed; yes, your key is already a good, well-behaved hash, so you don't need to apply a complex hash function over it go get the expected hash properties *and* you won't get collisions of the type "different data map to the same hash"; but in general if you have a decent hash function most collisions don't come from the hash function mapping the same key to the same hash, but from the current size of the hash table - i.e. from the fact that *multiple hash values* are mapped to the same bucket. So, again, you aren't going to gain much.

Comment: A `string` can also be a key.

Comment: @Ajay: I don't get it, you mean that in the same map you want to put both hashes and unrelated strings as key'

Comment: Just because the keys are guaranteed to be collision free doesn't mean you can just take an abusers subset of the bus and expect that to produce a good hash value.

Comment: @MikeMB: the fact that the keys are collision-free is of no interest; the point is that they are SHA-1 hashes, which are well-distributed by construction. You can take whatever fixed subset of bytes you like, and the result will be just as well distributed.

Comment: @MatteoItalia, No. I mean instead of just `size_t`, `std::string` can also be a key type. So, I can fill up the `string` object with 20 bytes.

Comment: @Ajay: the key type can be whatever has an equality operator and has an overload of `std::hash` that takes it as input; the point is that the result of the hash function that `std::unordered_set` expects is a `size_t`, so you cannot just use a custom `std::hash` that lets those 20 bytes "pass through" and have `unordered_set` use them as-is as hash value.

Answer (score 5):

A hasher for [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) must satisfy the [Hash concept](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Hash). So it must return a `std::size_t`, which is extremely unlikely to be more than 20 bytes.

Therefore it is not possible to provide an identity hasher for this 20-byte hash, and so even if no collision is guaranteed for the 20-byte hash, unless it can be reliably reduced to a 32-bit space (or rather a `sizeof(std::size_t)` space) without collision, collisions will be unavoidable for this case and this container.